# Can Singleton Inheritance be achieved in iOS

Tags: ios, design-patterns, singleton

I have couple of classes that should be inherited from some `A` class.

Each of them should be a Singleton.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This realization of Singleton-pattern allows the inheritance:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSMutableDictionary *sharedInstances;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{ /* This code fires only once */

        // Creating of the container for shared instances for different classes
        sharedInstances = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });

    id sharedInstance;

    @synchronized(self) { /* Critical section for Singleton-behavior */

        // Getting of the shared instance for exact class
        sharedInstance = sharedInstances[NSStringFromClass(self)];

        if (!sharedInstance) {
            // Creating of the shared instance if it's not created yet
            sharedInstance = [self new];
            sharedInstances[NSStringFromClass(self)] = sharedInstance;
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a Registry pattern?

Comment: Yes, it is a Registry pattern inside of your Singleton realization. The Registry is necessary here because it helps to store the instances of different classes of the hierarсhy.
Does this realization generally work as you expect?

Comment: Yes, this is how I've implemented it. I thought maybe there is something simpler. But this is cool too :) Thanks

Comment: Hello, Can you help write same with swift 3

Answer (score 2):

You never, ever inherit from a Singleton class. That completely breaks the concept of a Singleton in a bad way.

Having multiple singleton classes inheriting from the same base class: No problem whatsoever. In fact, most singletons have the common superclass NSObject, but you can use any other superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm not sure if you're familiar with Obj-C singleton patterns, but here is a guide:
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

There shouldn't be any more complications in subclassing. Just create a subclass of the singleton, and it will inherit it's singleton abilities as well. I think each subclass will create it's own unique singleton, but if not, override the singleton generator so it's unique for that subclass.

Keep in mind, singletons are falling out of favor on iOS, so they should be used sparingly. I try to only use them when attempting to create multiple instances is simply not possible (i.e. a class for accessing a hardware resource that must be reserved exclusively by a class.)

Comment: Actually, singletons are falling out of favour generally. Search for information on dependency injection. Singletons make it hard to test code although the initialisers for view controllers etc make it difficult to use dependency injection in all cases on ios

Comment: That is the problem exactly, each subclass will not create it's own unique singleton, unless you override the singleton generator in every class. And I really do not want to do that, because I have a lot of subclasses and all the generators are the same. So it makes a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Paulw11 is correct. Singletons make it harder to reduce memory consumption when needed, harder to reset state, and they're extremely unworkable for unit testing.

Luda: You might be able to use NSStringFromClass to get the class name of the current subclass, and save each singleton individually. You could use an NSDictionary to store the singletons. I don't know how well that works under Swift (I THINK NSStringFromClass still works as expected with Swift classes), but it will definitely work with Obj-C. Just a little more elbow grease required.